# How do I print something on a separate line while keeping everything aligned?

Tags: python, list, function

QUESTION SOLVED!! :) 
So I almost finished building the framework of a cinema program, but the problem is that my two headings (a-x and 1-23) are getting combined together every time, rather than being in a separate line. I tried getting them together into a single loop, putting one loop inside the other, and a couple other things, but this is the only thing I couldn't end up fixing in this program. If someone can tell me what is the problem, it would be great!!

**My code**

```
import string
rows = 9
seats = 24
x = 8
y = 0
z = 0
sold = [None] * rows #init empty rows
#init all seats to False (not sold)


for column in range(1, 24):
    print ("%10s" % y),
    y += 1    
for column in range(1, 24):
    print ("%10s" % string.ascii_lowercase[z]),
    z += 1
for row in range(rows) :
    sold[row] = [x] + [False]*seats
    x -= 1
    for column in range(len(sold[0])):  
        print ("%10s" % sold[row][column]),
    print()
#None is a special value that can act as a placeholder
```

Basically this part is for the numbers,

```
for column in range(1, 24):
    print ("%10s" % y),
    y += 1
```

and this part is for the alphabets.

```
for column in range(1, 24):
    print ("%10s" % string.ascii_lowercase[z]),
    z += 1
```

What would I be missing in my code??

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ohh, I'm using 2. I think that's why the end = ' ' threw an error for me..

Comment: Right. In 3.x, where `end=' '` works, the trailing commas would have no meaningful effect (since `print` is now a function, the effect is to just take the `None` return value and pack it into a tuple).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh I just got it. Another guy who answered this question deleted their answer right away for some reason, and his solution was to print | between the two loops. This worked for some reason.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks a lot for the help anyways! Have a great Sunday :)

Comment: Can you show what your expected output is?

Answer (score 0):

`print` takes an optional argument, `end`, to specify what to print after the thing you are printing.  The default is `\n`; if you used `''` instead, you could get all of your column things on a single line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually want to have a line between the numbers part and the alphabet part in my code. What will I have to do in that case??

Comment: I don't think I understand. Could you show, for a small set of rows and columns, *exactly* what the *complete* output should be, edited into the original question?